# How to get the names of embedded resx files

Tags: c#, .net

I need a little advice on how to get the names of the resx embedded files. I have a Languages folder and in it resx files and I would like to get the names of these files.

I tried to do this:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
string[] resourceNames = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
string folderName = "Languages";

foreach (string resourceName in resourceNames)
{
    if (resourceName.StartsWith(folderName) && resourceName.EndsWith(".resx"))
    {
        string fileName = resourceName.Substring(folderName.Length + 1);
        Console.WriteLine(fileName);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please pay attention to the tags you really select. Pressing a single letter and then `Enter` will likely not be correct. Like in your case where you selected the C language tag instead of the C# tag.

Comment: Is this an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)? I never ever needed to know this information and am simply using the C# wrapper classes around my RESX files that VS generates. So why do you need to know these internals?

Comment: I would like to list these files so the user can see which resx files are available. I'm a beginner so I don't know if I'm doing it right.

Comment: In my opinion, you are doing it wrong, as these RESX files are compiled into separate DLLs. If you really insist of showing this to your user, maybe [this chapter about enumerating resources might help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/work-with-resx-files-programmatically#enumerate-resources).